# Binary reader peek byte in C#

Tags: c#, binaryreader, peek

I wish to peek a byte of the binary data coming in using binary reader. Using PeekChar works fine only if it is UTF-8. Otherwise, I get the error "The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback".

Is there a way for binary reader to peek one byte irrespective of the encoding?

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
type = (uint)reader.PeekChar(); // Throws error I mentioned for a particular case
```

Comment: Is the data text? UTF8 can have multi-byte characters. Are you looking for the next character or the next byte?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No. Its binary data. I am looking for the next byte.

Answer (score 3):

`BinaryReader` can't peek a single byte, as simple as that. However, in your case, it's not really important. Since you have a `MemoryStream` underlying the `BinaryReader`, you can safely do a `ReadByte` and just move the `Position` back one byte.

Comment: I was looking for Peek method for memory stream. i didnt know i can change position. thanks.

Comment: i am looking for a way to do this on a non-ending networkstream, is there a way to do this with a streamlayer that buffers the history?

Comment: @Droa I'd avoid trying that, network streams are complicated enough as is. Why not deal with peeking on the application level? But if you really want to, making your own stream that buffers a single byte on the underlying stream is pretty easy. Just make sure you handle closing the stream properly :)